# Prove that the greatest prime divisor $ q$ of $ 2^p-1$ satisfies the inequality $ 2^q>(6p)^{2p}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $ p$ be a prime of the form  $ 4k+1$ such that
>   $$ p^2|2^p-2$$. Prove that the greatest prime divisor  $ q$ of $ 2^p-1$
>   satisfies the inequality $$ 2^q>(6p)^{2p}$$

my attemp: let $2^p-1=\prod q_{i}$,where $q_{i}$ are primes (not necessarily distinct).we have $q_{i}=k_{i}p+1$ for some postive integer $k_{i}$,then I can't

Comment: Do you have an example of a prime $p$ of the form $4k+1$ such that $p^ 2$ divides $2^p-2$?

Comment: Note that $q \neq p$; otherwise $p^2 < \frac1{18}$.

Comment: I think if $p^2 | 2^p-2$, then $p^2 | 2^{p-1}-1$, so $p$ is a *Wieferich* prime. The only known Weiferich primes up till now are  $1093$ and $3511$, and only the former is of the form $4k+1$. I don't know whether the statement you are making is true for $1093$,though.

Comment: How did you come across this problem?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The statement is true for $1093$ as the greatest prime divisor of $2^{1093}-1$ is $1109058770941807305887312153229026337109997438530131204869911025623527989895377920885257429230558993
8353242166551505231973795937381812374530733039613691398140158954888306711$, see [here](http://www.mersenne.ca/prp.php?show=2&min_exponent=1000&max_exponent=2000#M1093).

Comment: This paper https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-28.pdf by Erdos, has a result that there is an effectively computable constant $c>0$ such that $q>cp\log p$. This inequality is true regardless of $p$ being Weiferich prime.